# LayoutTransition / Animation in android is only working in Infinite while loop

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-animation, kotlin-coroutines

I'm creating some buttons dynamically in android like this..

```
private fun createButton() {
        val randomHeight = (100..1000).random()
        val button = Button(this, null, R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle)
        val lp = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((1080 / 20), randomHeight)
        lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        button.id = btnId + 1
        button.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))
        if (btnId > 0)
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, btnId)
        root_layout.addView(button, lp)
        btnId++
        button.text = lp.height.toString()
        buttonList.add(button)
    }
```

Now in onCreate method, I'm calling this createButton function in a loop until my layout's width reaches my device's width like this.. root_layout's width is wrap content so it gives a very cool effect when buttons force the layout to expand...

```
 root_layout.layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_APPEARING)
    val displayWidth = getDisplayWidth()
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        //  while (root_layout.width < displayWidth -1) finite but does not give animation
        //infinite but gives animation
        while (root_layout.width <= displayWidth) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: ${root_layout.width} + $displayWidth ")
            createButton()
            delay(100)
        }
    }
```

Also on a button click, I change the height of all of the buttons randomly like this

```
 btn_ran -> {
            for (i:Button in buttonList) {
                if (!isRunningSearch) {
                    var r = (100..1000).random()
                    i.layoutParams.height = r
                    i.text = r.toString()
                    i.requestLayout()
                }
            }
        }
```

Now the problem is that the while loop in the onCreate is going infinite, but my btn_ran function works very fine because the height of buttons changes with animation but this happens only if my while loop goes infinite if I break my while loop somehow the btn_ran function works but without any animations.

I want to run my while loop till device-width only or for a fixed time but I also want buttons to change the height with animation as they are doing in an infinite loop.

Here are two gif one with infinite loop and animation another without an infinite loop without animation...

[image: Animated buttons but infinite loop..On btn_ran cliclk]
[image: Limited loop but without animation ...On btn_ran cliclk]

Comment: you are not updating root_layout.width variable inside while loop

Comment: root_layout's width is getting increased by createButton() function, root_layout width is wrap content so buttons increases it's width

Comment: no layout size will not increment immediately and 100ms might not be enough.

Comment: you need to use globalLayoutListener to observe changes

Comment: even if I move the while loop outside of coroutine scope, it still works the same

Comment: I just want to know why my buttons are getting animated if it is an infinite loop why are they not showing animation in case of finite loop